# How to filter a select box by data-attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter a select box `person` by data-attributes selected in another select box `invoice_project_id`:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="invoice_project_id">
  <option value="1">Project A</option>
  <option value="2">Project B</option>
  <option value="3">Project C</option>
</select>

<select id="person">
  <option data-project_ids="[1,2]">Spencer, Eve</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[3]">Goodwin, Alisha</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[]">Emard, Tito</option>
  <option data-project_ids="[2,3]">Bergstrom, Damien</option>
</select>
```

---

**Javascript:**

```
function filterOption(id) {
  return $('#person option').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
  });
}

$('#invoice_project_id').on('change', function () {
  var project = $('#invoice_project_id').val();
  $('#person option').hide();
  filterOption(+project).show();
});
```

I also built a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zdPY/).

The problem is that it's not working in Safari and Chrome. I am new to jQuery and basically copied & pasted the code together.

Can anybody tell me how to get it working?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding options is not cross browser compatible, so clone the options are try

```
function filterOption($opts, id) {
    return $opts.filter(function () {
        return $.inArray(id, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
    });
}

var $person = $('#person'),
    $popts = $person.children();
$('#invoice_project_id').on('change', function () {
    var project = $('#invoice_project_id').val();
    filterOption($popts.clone(), +project).appendTo($person.empty())
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T4LEp/)